# GroupBy and CountBy for multiple values

Tags: group-by, underscore.js

I am trying to use underscorejs to groupBy multiple values based on below data.

```
var obj = [
        {
            'Name': 'A',
            'Status': 'Ticket Closed'
        },{
            'Name': 'B',
            'Status': 'Ticket Open To Close'
        },{
            'Name': 'A',
            'Status': 'Ticket Closed'
        },{
            'Name': 'B',
            'Status': 'Ticket Open'
        },{
            'Name': 'A',
            'Status': 'Ticket Open To Closed'
        },{
            'Name': 'A',
            'Status': 'Ticket Open'
        },{
            'Name': 'B',
            'Status': 'Ticket Open'
        }
    ];
```

The expected output is

```
[{
    'Name': Closed',
    'Count': [2, 0]
},{
    'Name': Open',
    'Count': [2, 3]
}]
```

First object counts all closed tickets (Where the status contains the word closed) for A and B simultaneously. Similarly the second object counts for Open tickets. Here is what I tried

```
var arr = _.groupBy(obj, function (row) {
    return (row["Status"].indexOf('Open') > 0 ? "Open" : "Closed");
});

var arr1 = _.groupBy(arr["Closed"], 'Name');
var arr2 = _.groupBy(arr["Open"], 'Name');

var cData = [];
cData.push(arr1);
cData.push(arr2);
```

Unable to get count from same code. Any help?

Comment: I don't understand where the `[2,0]` and `[2,3]` numbers come from.

Comment: The [2,0] in the first array are the count of tickets which are closed (Considering the word open does not appear).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I was able to resolve this. Here's the working example

http://jsfiddle.net/7ETKV/

Here is the solved code:

```
var jsondata = jsondata.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
});
_.each(jsondata, function (row, idx) {
    ((row.Status.indexOf('Open') > 0) ? jsondata[idx].bgStatus = 'Open' : jsondata[idx].bgStatus = 'Closed');
});

var cdata = [], xobj = {};
var gd = _.groupBy(jsondata, 'bgStatus');
var cats = _.keys(_.groupBy(jsondata, 'Name'));

for (var p in gd) {
    var arr = _.countBy(gd[p], function (row) {
        return row.Name;
    });

    _.each(cats, function (row) {
        if (!arr.hasOwnProperty(row)) arr[row] = 0;
    });

    xobj.Name = p;
    xobj.Data = _.values(arr);

    cdata.push(xobj);
    xobj = {};
}
```

Hope might help someone. Any updates to the code / optimizations are welcome.